# Textbox for rowList instead of select in jqGrid pager

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, pager

Is it possible to have `textbox` and `button` to specify page size instead of having `select` with options.

I want pager like below

[image]

User can enter page number in first text box and refresh grid only when clicking on "Go" button and user can change page size by editing second text box and clicking on "Change" grid needs to refreshed with updated total number of pages,page size etc..

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try : http://neoalchemy.org/tablePagination.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is possible! [The demo](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ChangePageSize.htm) demonstrates one of the possible implementation. It uses external input control:

[image]

In the same way you can move the controls to the pager/pagers, you can force Click on the "Change" button on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and so on. I just wanted to demonstrate how the requirements could be implemented. I used both toppager and the second pager at the bottom on the demo to demonstrates that the approach works in the case too.

The code used in the demo is the following:

```
var getPagerSelectors = function () {
        return $("#list").closest(".ui-jqgrid").find(">.ui-jqgrid-view>.ui-jqgrid-toppager,>.ui-jqgrid-pager").find(".ui-pg-selbox");
    };
$("#setRowNum").button().click(function () {
    var newRowNum = parseInt($("#newRowNum").val(), 10);
    if (newRowNum > 0) {
        var $selects = getPagerSelectors();
        var $firstOption = $selects.find("option:nth-child(1)");
        $firstOption.text(newRowNum);
        $firstOption.val(newRowNum);
        $selects.first().val(newRowNum);
        $selects.first().trigger("change");
    }
});
getPagerSelectors().hide();
```

If one removed the last line (`getPagerSelectors().hide();`) one will see that I just change the value of the first option in the `<select>` used by jqGrid for choosing the page size, set the option as selected and trigger `"change"` event in the first pager. It's all.

**UPDATED**: [One more demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ChangePageSize1.htm) uses `insertAfter` to move controls used for entering new page size. The results looks like below

[image]

I used the following CSS styles

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager, .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager {
    height: auto !important;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

to improve a little the height of the pager after adding new components.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to jqGrid. How can place text box and button in pager.

Comment: @malkam: `getPagerSelectors()` function helps you to select the selector. jQuery methods like `after`, `insertAfter` and many other allows you to **move** some elements in another place on the page. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ChangePageSize1.htm) could be the simplest example what one can do. It uses `<span id="mycontrols">...</span>` with contains all new controls and it uses `$("#mycontrols").insertAfter(getPagerSelectors().first());` to move the controls.

Comment: @malkam: I made more example for you which shows how to **move** input elements within the pager. See **UPDATED** part of my answer.